# Why don't we dribble tears through our nose?

Tags: human-physiology

Basal tears are tears produced by the lacrimal gland and they lubricate the eye. They are then funneled into the lacrimal sac and then from there into the nose eventually.

If this is the case, why don't we constantly dribble out tears from our nose? Where do the tears go?